# Conditionally extract hashes from array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

From the following array of hashes:

```
x = [
  {"creationDate"=>123456,"createdBy"=>"test_user1"},
  {"creationDate"=>123459,"createdBy"=>"test_user1"},
  {"creationDate"=>123458,"createdBy"=>"test_user1"},
  {"creationDate"=>123454,"createdBy"=>"test_user2"},
  {"creationDate"=>123452,"createdBy"=>"test_user2"},
  {"creationDate"=>123451,"createdBy"=>"test_user2"}
]
```

I am trying to find the maximum `:creationDate` value where `:createdBy` value  is `"test_user1"`. I did this:

```
x.map {|a| a['creationDate'] if a['createdBy'] == 'test_user1'}
# => [123456,123459,123458,nil,nil,nil]
```

I want to get rid of the `nil` so that I can apply `max` to that array. How do I modify the code above?

Comment: @YuHao: I think it is valid syntax in new ruby

Comment: @YuHao http://stackoverflow.com/a/27759858/125816

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. Voted to close.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Indeed it is valid syntax, but note that the result cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @sawa: yeah, he messed up the example

Comment: Sorry for using : instead of =>

Comment: Close the question if you don't want people with similar problems to look at the solution. I got what i needed. Also, try understanding the fact that i am new to ruby, hence asking this question.

Comment: Telling a lie has nothing to do with being new to Ruby.

Comment: So you are saying that i am lying because i could not copy paste the massive input to my small snipet and had to make a sample input on this UI (where tabs dont work and i have to manually enter 4 spaces on each line) so that people can understand the question better? If you have such a problem understanding the context of the question, just ignore the question and solve someone else's doubt. M sure there are people (like others who answered) who can use common sense. Also, i said sorry, what more do you want me to do?

Comment: You lied because you wrote that your code returned `[123456,123459,123458,nil,nil,nil]` while it didn't. It returned `[nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil]` (before your edit).

Comment: Untrue. I got what i wrote. And just to be sure, i ran the exact thing in my question again and got the same output. It is not my problem you cannot reproduce it. I dont appreciate being called a liar on a public forum. If you have something personal against me, lets take this up privately. Also, i didnt ask you to reply on this thread. You chose to. So, why dont you reply on threads that you find "Honest" as you define it.

Comment: Consider selecting an answer if you found at least one to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
x.map {|a| a['creationDate'] if a['createdBy'] == 'test_user1'}.compact.max
# => 123459
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is:

```
x.select { |record| record[:createdBy] == 'test_user1' }.map { |record| record[:creationDate] }.max
  # => 123459
```

In general, to remove `nil`s from an array, you can simply call `Array#compact`:

```
[1, nil, nil, 2, 'foo', nil].compact # => [1, 2, "foo"]
```

Comment: Thanks for .compact.
That is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It' close to what you plan to do in python:

```
x.select { |n| n[:createdBy] == "test_user1" }.max_by { |n| n[:creationDate] }
```

First operation select on records created by "test_user1", while second operation get the maximum of the resulting array based on the creationDate

Comment: This returns the record (hash) and not the max date itself.

Comment: @Krule be carefull with edition: I was reusing the same convention than the poster, and the poster use string based hash and not atom based hash, so your edit will fails...

Comment: It is not actually string based hash. In that case he would have to use `=>`. This code would return `nil`: `x.select { |n| n["createdBy"] == "test_user1" }.max_by { |n| n["creationDate"] }`

Comment: @krule : you're right, I thought that it was a typing error but I was not aware of the 'key':value syntax, only the key:value one (which I think create more issue than it solve....)

Comment: @tomsoft: That syntax is rarely used since it was introduced in Ruby 2.2. I prefer previous approach to this (ruby 2, 2.1) `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>` (ruby 1.9) `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end`. But with language tendency to make strings immutable (in ruby 3) and aversion towards symbols, I can understand the decision. Also a lot of people made this mistake.

Comment: Just tack `["creation_date"]` to the end to return the requested value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess something like :

```
x.delete_if {|x| x == nil}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for a map-reduce function such as [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

```
x = [{"creationDate" => 123456,"createdBy" => "test_user1"},
     {"creationDate" => 123459,"createdBy" => "test_user1"},
     {"creationDate" => 123458,"createdBy" => "test_user1"},
     {"creationDate" => 123454,"createdBy" => "test_user2"},
     {"creationDate" => 123452,"createdBy" => "test_user2"},
     {"creationDate" => 123451,"createdBy" => "test_user2"}]

x.inject(nil) do |result, item|
  if item["createdBy"] == "test_user1" && (result.nil? or item["creationDate"] > result)
    item["creationDate"]
  else
    result
  end
end
```

Here's a possible implementation of the `inject`. The block will iterate each item in the collection and will always maintain the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

```
x.min_by{|h| [h[:createdBy], -h[:creationDate]]}[:creationDate]
# => 123459
```

---

```
[123456, 123459, 123458, nil, nil, nil].compact
# => [123456, 123459, 123458]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.